# System error in Apache with combination of https redirection plus password requirement plus error document

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, errordocument

In an Apache 2 vhost I have the following configuration (in my case, in `.htaccess` of the document root (which is for simplicity the same for http:80 and https:443)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

in order to redirect any http-connections to https
Moreover,

```
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 402 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
```

to produce custom error messages. The third ingredient is a protected subfolder with authentication required (per `.htaccess` in that folder):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Test"
AuthUserFile  /some/path/to/passwords
Require user joe
```

Everything works fine except when someone tries to retrieve `http://example.com/protectedfolder` In fact, what happens is that the client gets a `302 Found` reply with redirection to `https://example.com/error.php`

On the other hand,

- `https://example.com/protectedfolder` leads to a custom (i.e., produced by error.php) `401` as expected.
- `http://example.com/publicfolder` leads to `302` redirect to `https://example.com/publicfolder`, then a `301` permanent redirect to `https://example.com/publicfolder/`, and finally (as DirectoryIndex is disabled) a customized `403` error. As expected.
- Also,  `http://example.com/nonexistent` causes a `302` to `https://example.com/nonexistent` and then a customized `404`, also as expected.
- If I disable the `ErrorDocument 401` configuration, a query for `http://example.com/protectedfolder` causes `401` immediately, i.e., without redirection to https.

There is no specific entry in Apache error.log, but it seems that the problem occurs because the Auth requirement is evaluated before the Rewrite, thus invokes the ErrorDocument and that is wrongly still http??

> What do I need to change in order to have the desired effect, i.e., that `http://example.com/protectedfolder` causes a redirect to `https://example.com/protectedfolder` and only that redirected URL causes a (customized)  `401`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do unconditional redirect from `http` to `https` ([a bad idea if you want everyone to be able to access the public information on your web-site](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2716278), BTW), then you should just make separate host entries for `:80` and `:443`, and point the `:80` entry towards something like an empty folder — then you wouldn't have mod_auth competing with mod_rewrite.